# Parallel development of library and application with seperate repositories in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm developing a library, which is to be used by multiple applications. Now I started working on an application (in a seperate repository with a different remote), which has a reference to the library .dll

To make parallel development of both the library and the application easier, I tried to add the library.csproj to my applications solution. This seems to break stuff, the `using library` in classes of my application gets confused, as both the referenced dll (this is what application should use) and the added project both are in the same scope.

I'm hoping there is another way than just opening both project in seperate instances of vs.

Comment: Develop them separately.  Separate unit tests, separate integration tests etc.  If your library need a new feature, write and test it separately.

Comment: @Neil ok, that is definetely my Intention, I guess my question is - is there a way to develop them seperately in one vs window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used them to suggest a concrete workflow, but I think that [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are trying to solve this exact same problem. It might be worth exploring in your situation, if you insist on having them in the same folder.

By the way, consider to use the library as a NuGet package. This will help you in the future as well, it's really incovenient to reference a dll file directly.